# Android Studio Change Array Value

Tags: android, arrays, generator

Hi i would like to know if there is a method that takes an element of my array and deleting it depending the answer of the user.For example in my code i have an array of countries and a random generator that display a country to a textView for the user.If the user press yes button then the generator runs.If the user press no button nothing happens so far but the idea is to delete the element of the array that is displaying and generator will run again but with this element deleted.`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.No);
    final Button yes=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Yes);
    final TextView tvMessage=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);



    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String[] country = new String[10];
            country[0] = "greece";
            country[1] = "germany";
            country[2] = "america";
            country[3] = "serbia";
            country[4] = "france";
            country[5] = "england";
            country[6] = "cyprus";
            country[7] = "japan";
            country[8] = "russia";
            country[9] = "china";
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randome = rand.nextInt(10);
            tvMessage.setText(country[randome]);

        }
    });




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ArrayList to delete dynamic index value

```
ArrayList<String> customlist = new ArrayList<String>();
customlist.addAll(country);
customlist.remove(randome);


String []copycountry = new String[customlist.size()];
customlist.toArray(copycountry);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious help

Comment: Also something else if i want to display the cities of the country the user typed yes,for example if he types yes to greece i want to run a random generator with the cities of greece.Is there a way to give id to arraylist on value "greece" that i can create then another arraylist containing the cities and then run it???

Comment: for best result use array list instead of String Array.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use List when array size is not fixed.

```
  int randome=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.No);
    final Button yes=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Yes);
    final TextView tvMessage=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

    final ArrayList<String> country = new ArrayList<>();
    country.add("greece");
    country.add("germany");
    country.add("america");
    country.add("serbia");
    country.add("france");
    country.add("england");
    country.add("cyprus");
    country.add("japan");
    country.add("russia");
    country.add("china");
    no.setsetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (randome>=0 && randome<country.size()){
                country.remove(randome);
            }
        }
    });
    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            randome = rand.nextInt(country.size());
            tvMessage.setText(country.get(randome));

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious help

Comment: Also something else if i want to display the cities of the country the user typed yes,for example if he types yes to greece i want to run a random generator with the cities of greece.Is there a way to give id to arraylist on value "greece" that i can create then another arraylist containing the cities and then run it???

Comment: Also something else if i want to display the cities of the country the user typed yes,for example if he types yes to greece i want to run a random generator with the cities of greece.Is there a way to give id to arraylist on value "greece" that i can create then another arraylist containing the cities and then run it???